# How to open new functionality in new tabs in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am developing an eclipse plugin, I have three functionalities. As of now, all the three functionalities are displayed in a single composite in the same tab.
I need to open all the three functions in three different tabs.So Help me to open a new tab form code level in java.

Comment: Is this a view? an editor? an e4 part? Are you asking about tabs in the same part or multiples parts?

Comment: It's a view. I need to open them in multiple tabs in the same part. @greg-449

Comment: Or open multiple tabs in the same grid. Is it possible?

Comment: Use CTabFolder for tabs

Comment: Thanks man.. It helped me. I used tabFolder